# How efficient is .NET framework's DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula.Mean() versus just creating a list, enumerating, summation and dividing?

Tags: c#, performance, mean

I attempted to use ILSpy to take a look at `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` at the function `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula.Mean()` and it doesn't appear to be able to render the contents.

I am curious, is this function more efficient at producing a mean than simply writing my own mean function, such as [follows](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/StatisticalfunctionsMean.htm):

```
   public static double Mean(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        foreach(double d in values)
        {
            sum += d;
            count++;
        }

        return sum / count;
    }
```

I am likely going to be dealing with 3 million or more members.

**[UPDATE]**

During testing, LINQ's `IEnumerable.Average()` seems very efficient on my old dual core workstation, processing a `List<int>` of 87000 members in 0.0011471 seconds.  This is much more efficient than I thought it would be:

```
var s3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
double average1 = DaySampleValues.Average();
s3.Stop();
TimeSpan totaltime = s3.Elapsed; // = 0.0011471 seconds
```

Comment: Write the same code using both and compare them? That said this is an O(n) operation so it's unlikely there's some deep optimisations going on in the library.

Comment: Could you not download the source code and check it out? ... http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx ....

Comment: Thanks Arran.  Kudos to MSFT for making the page not _quite_ work in Chrome.  I guess that was a cool thing to do in 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average is an `O(n)` operation, so there's probably not much you can do to optimize it within C#.  You could *try* parallelizing it with:

```
values.AsParallel().Average();
```

but the overhead of parallelization may be more than the benefit of running multiple threads simultaneously.

The only other optimization would be to replace the `count` measurement with a call to `values.Count()`.  If the underlying data structure is a `List` or `Array` then `Count()` will be `O(1)` and may save you a bit of computing time.

In any case, the only way to get a true answer is to *measure it*.  Try it each way and see which one is faster.  If possible, try them on different system architectures as well to see the benefit of multiple-cores, more memory, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.  I'll keep this in mind.  After looking at these functions, I feel like this is more than likely how `DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula.Mean()` implements its work.  I'll accept your answer, as it clarifies several points, and also proves that the only way to determine what's more efficient is to test.

Answer (score 0):

or can't you use LINQ .Average()?